# Enable a select box on choosing an option from previous select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three select boxes on a page and I want to keep the second and third select box disabled until a choice has been made in the first one, and similarly keep the third one disabled until a choice has been made in the second select box. And I want to populate the second select box one the basis of the choice made in the first select box. for e.g. if samsung is the choice made in first box then I want the samsung models only to appear in second select box.

This is m HTML code.

```
<html>
<head>


<style>
select {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  background-color:#58B14C;
  background-position:initial initial;
  background-repeat:initial initial;
  border:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
  border-top-left-radius:8px;
  border-top-right-radius:8px;
  color:#EEEEEE;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left:3px;
  padding:2px 10px;
  width:347px;
  background:url("img/arrow.gif") no-repeat scroll 316px 6px black;
  background-size: 16px;

}
select option{
    background-color: black;
}
#mainselection { overflow:hidden; width:352px;
-moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
background:grey; 
float: left;
}

.stepsClass{
    float:left;
}
body{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form style="position:absolute;left: 15%;top: 25%;">
        <div class="stepsClass"><input type="image" src="img/step1.png"></br><div id="mainselection">
    <select id="Brand">
<option>Select your cellphone Brand</option>
<option>Blackberry</option>
<option>I-phone</option>
<option>Samsung</option>
<option>HTC</option>
<option>Nokia</option>
<option>Motorola</option>
</select>
    </div></div>
      <div class="stepsClass"><input type="image" src="img/step2.png"></br>  <div id="mainselection">
<select id="Model">
<option>Select your cellphone Model</option>
<option>Blackberry</option>
<option>I-phone</option>
<option>Samsung</option>
<option>HTC</option>
<option>Nokia</option>
<option>Motorola</option>
</select>
          </div></div>
        <div class="stepsClass"><input type="image" src="img/step3.png"></br>
        <div id="mainselection">
<select id="Carrier">
<option>Select your Carrier</option>
<option>Blackberry</option>
<option>I-phone</option>
<option>Samsung</option>
<option>HTC</option>
<option>Nokia</option>
<option>Motorola</option>
</select>
        </div></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sorry for not uploading the images I am assuming they are not of any relevance to this question. I am also adding jQuery tag because there are people who find it easier to write javascript in jQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your HTML select options to have a value attribute.I believe this would allow you to populate the second select box one the basis of the choice made in the first select box.

```
  <select id="Brand">
  <option value = "">Select your cellphone Brand</option>
  <option value = "BB">Blackberry</option>
  <option value = "ios">I-phone</option>
  <option value = "sam">Samsung</option>
  <option value = "htc">HTC</option>
  <option value = "nokia">Nokia</option>
  <option value = "mot">Motorola</option>
  </select>


<select id="Model" >
    <option>Select Your Model No.</option>
</select>
Javascrpt



$(function(){
    $("#Model").attr("disabled","true");
    $("#Brand").change(function(){
        if(this.value != ""){
          $('#Model').removeAttr('disabled');
           var brand = $("#Brand option:selected").text();
            document.getElementById("Model").options.length = 1;
            for(var i = 0; i < 10 ;i++){
                var selectOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
                selectOption.text = brand + " Model No." + i;
                document.getElementById('Model').appendChild(selectOption);
            } 
$("#Model").selectmenu("refresh","true");            
        }
        else{
            $("#Model").attr("disabled","true"); 
            $("#Model").val("");            
            $("#Model").selectmenu("refresh","true");      
        }
    });
})
```

Hope it serves your purpose.

Comment: The selection can be retrieved even without the value attribute. That is not the issue. I want to know how to populate it. I can catch the value on trigger of change in selection. But I want to know how to populate the select box. The script for populating not the script for catching the event. May be I did not phrase the question properly. Sorry for that. But thanks for the effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have edited my ans to populate the model drop down as per selection.. I hope this satifies your req.. 
See it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/ByfFn/4/

Comment: That is actually a cool script you have wriiten. I can see that you have written a for loop to populate the second select box. Is there a way where I could populate the the select in jus one execution. Like suppose I have the whole select box written already and stored in a variable then could I just populate the whole set in one command. And also how do you clean the old options from the select box. I see it happening in your code, but just for the learning purpose how is it happening. Thanks for the help..

Comment: I am clearing the options using this line in the code document.getElementById("Model").options.length = 1;
Yes you can populate the select box in one execution by storing the options as a string in a var and using the innerHTML attribute of the select box.

Answer (score 1):

Disable required(2nd and 3rd) lists by adding `disabled="disabled"`

```
$(function(){
      // The following will enable the 2nd drop down list when 1st one will be changed/selected.
      $('#Brand').change(function(){
         $('#Model').removeAttr('disabled');
      });   

      // This block will enable the 3rd list when you change the 2nd list.
      $('#Model').change(function(){
         $('#Carrier').removeAttr('disabled');
      }) ;
});
```

Comment: But how will it be disabled in the first place.

Comment: Check the edited answer, hope this will help. Let me know if you still have any doubt.

Comment: I was asking how to disable it in the first place, but its ok I used onLoad document.getElementById("Model").disabled=true; Now my other problem is to populate the second select box on the basis of choice made in the first select box.

Comment: In the question you have mentioned to enable the list box, enabling and populating are different. You can make them disable only by adding  disable="disabled" in the HTML tag for your select. No need to do it by using getElementById().

Answer (score 0):

you can disabled the copmbobox in jquery like this:

```
$("#cbCountry").combobox("option", "disabled", true);
```

chk your condition and then disable the combobox as per your condition